# python excel file update

Tags: excel, python-3.x, updates

Hello I wrote a program which is connected to an excel file. Whenever I add new guests + information in the program it's also adding them to the excel file. Nevertheless, whenever I start the program again to add another guest or remove someone it starts all over again and I have to type in everything again.Is there any way to keep the Information in the excel file and just update it based on the things I change when I start the program again?

This my code..

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import pandas as pd

fileName = r'/Users/Jannik/Downloads/Storage/WeddingPlanner.csv'

print ('Hi. Let\'s organize the wedding!')

def menu():
print ('1. Find a guest')
print ('2. Add a guest')
print ('3. Remove a guest')
print ('4. Change a guests information')
print ('5. Quit')
print ()


guestList = {'kerstin hueneke' : {'phone': 3892881920, 'over night': 'yes', 'company': 1},
        'uncle ollo': {'phone': 8724618739, 'over night': 'yes', 'company': 0},
        'franck rohling': {'phone' : 9125329667, 'over night': 'yes', 'company': 3},
        'speedy wosz':{'phone' : 3527128449, 'over night': 'no', 'company': 3},
         'aunt jutta': {'phone': 7226189446, 'over night': 'no', 'company': 1}}

 guestListPD = pd.DataFrame(guestList)
 guestListPD.to_csv(r'/Users/Jannik/Downloads/Storage/WeddingPlanner.csv')

choice = 0
menu ()

while choice != 5:
choice = int(input('Type in a number (1-5):'))
try:
    if choice == 1:
        print ('Find a guest:')
        name = input ('name:')
        print (name, guestList[name])
except KeyError:
        print (name, 'was not found')

if choice == 2:
    print ('Add name, phone number, stay and company information')
    name = input ('name:')
    phone = input ('phone number:')
    stay = input ('over night - yes or no?')
    company = input ('number of company:')
    guestList[name] = phone, stay, company
    print ('The guest was added to the guestlist')

if choice == 3:
    print ('Remove a guest')
    name = input ('name:')
    if name in guestList:
        del guestList [name]
        print ('Your guest was removed from the guestlist')
    else:
        print (name, 'was not found')

if choice == 4:
    print ('Change guest information')
    name = input ('name:?')
    phone = input ('phone number:?')
    stay = input ('over night- yes or no?')
    company = input ('number of company:?')
    if name in guestlist:
        guestList[name] = phone, stay, company

if choice != 5:
    menu ()


print ('\n See you next time!\n')

for z in guestList:
print (z, guestList[z])

print()

guestListPD = pd.DataFrame(guestList)

print (guestListPD)
```

I'm using python 3.5. Thanks!

Comment: 1. If you want your guestlist to be saved, you should write it to the csv at the end of your program in stead of at the beginning.

Comment: 2. If you don't want to start over again from the start each time, you should initialise your guest list by reading from the csv, in stead of initialising it hardcoded.